# View onTouchListener problems with status bar hidden

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

i am trying to implement an app that keeps the toolbar,the status bar and the navigation bar hidden, but when the user touches the screen they should re-appear. things seem to work ok, when i first hide the elements using

```
 View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
            int uiOptions =View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
toolbar.setTranslationY(-toolbar.getHeight());
```

but when i touch the screen, the status bar and the navigation bar re-appear.
(the toolbar does not.) and ANOTHER touch does get caught by the listener.

i've done step-by-step debugging, but the first touch, (which make the status bar and the navigation bar appear) doesn't get recognized by the listener..
the second one does. 
i've tried looking into the View class code, i put a breakpoint on it's 
OnTouchEvent method, but it never gets called.. or it's not possible to include 
that in my debugging... (working with android studio.)
any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only solution I've had success with is to listen for changes in the UI Visibility and perform whatever it is you wanted to do in your touch event there as well.

```
root.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
        if (visibility == 0) {
            // nav & status bar visible, treat as touch event
        }
    }
});
```